# Building complex shapes with CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm working on a project for iphone and android browsers that requires that I build a thermometer-like progress meter that can react with browser resizing and easily be able to change the progress. It needs to be like the design as much as possible. That is, it needs the fancy gradients, inset highlighting, the border.

The Meter:

[image]

Notice the white inset shadow and border

The progress should extend into the circular portion as well and continue to have the fancy effects.

I went ahead and got a rough prototype working (tested in chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/xduQ9/3/

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 25px;
}

.circle {
  margin-left: -6px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 24px;
  border: solid rgba(178, 181, 188, 0.8) 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 0 #fff, inset 1px -2px 0 #fff, inset -2px 0 0 #fff, inset -2px -2px 0 #fff, inset 0 3px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35), -20px -20px 0 #fff, 20px -20px 0 #fff, 20px 20px 0 #fff, -20px 20px 0 #fff;
}

.circle-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 48px;
  height: 51px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 51px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  background: url("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/905197/white-stripe-diagonal.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(183, 237, 21, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 186, 24, 1) 28%, rgba(78, 126, 11, 1) 65%, rgba(59, 86, 0, 1) 99%);
}

.meter.complete .progress {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: progress-slide 0.6s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes progress-slide {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 25px 25px;
  }
}

.progress-cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 9px 0 0 9px;
  border: solid #70901b 1px;
  border-right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.top-mask {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  margin-left: -45px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: solid #b2b5bc 1px;
  border-radius: 0 0 33px 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 0 #fff, 0 3px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
}

.bottom-mask {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 17px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  margin-left: -45px;
  background: white;
  border-top: solid #b2b5bc 1px;
  border-radius: 0 19px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 1px -2px 0 #fff;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 2px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 12px;
  border: solid 3px #fff;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.meter {
  position: relative;
}

.left-border {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  left: -4px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 12px 0 0 12px;
  border: solid 1px #b2b5bc;
  border-right: none;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="meter complete">
  <!-- Remove .complete to stop animation -->
  <div class="left-border">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="progress"></div>
    <div class="top-mask"></div>
    <div class="bottom-mask"></div>
    <div class="circle-wrap">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The technique basically clips a rectangle with a striped green background with a few divs with rounded corners until the desired shape comes out. Then I use a bunch of shadows to add padding and the inset around the meter.

My question: What would you do? I mean, I can optimize this solution a little. I could add more markup to get the design just right, but it feels so dirty. And I have a feeling it won't be easy to cross-browser test. I thought about using canvas, but having to redraw the shapes if the browser resizes is sucky.

I'd like to avoid using images as much as possible, but if an elegant solution is possible with them, I'll definitely use it.

While having the ability to change the color of the progress bar isn't a requirement of the implementation, I'd like a solution that has that ability.

Comment: Updated fiddle with the `-moz-` vendor prefix for Firefox. It doesn't look as well as in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/xduQ9/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fiddle don't work in firefox (Aurora) or IE.

I know you prefer not using images but I think this would be alot cleaner in the code if you use just images.

Why? because you can create a sprite with 3 parts:
First part has the outer piece of the meter with the part of the bar transparent, second part has the "bar" and third part is just white to hide the bar and give the impression of percentages.

Then you do a simple javascript code for hidinging percentages of the bar starting right (like if user has 24 percent then position -76px).

I would have drawn the bar exactly as it shows full and use z-index to put the meter on top, then the white part to fake progress.
And a big circle in the beginning.

The circle will fill the round part in the end (i dont know what the current meter looks like there, if you have the line straight there then go with a square instead of circle).

Did a sketch in paint:

[image]

This version will be easier than pure CSS and will look alike on all browsers.
Resizing is also doable with some scripting in a fluid div and fluid image sizes.

Once you have a ratio you want to work with the rest is simple-ish.

Comment: I liked the previous diagram! But yeah, I get it. I thought of going this route in the beginning but the mad scientist in me decided to CSS it out. Also, our designer works in Fireworks, so every time I have to edit his stuff I want to punch a baby.

Comment: haha the handdrawn one? i noticed you had rounded borders so a square wouldnt do it. :) I also edited the post so you can do the animation (didnt know there was one at first). But just animate the bar and do percentages with the hiding white part.

Comment: It really looks like I'll have to go this route to ensure its consistent across all browser versions. Sad day. I just wish I could change the color of the progress bar with just CSS. Oh well

Answer (score 2):

You have to be ready to give up some of the visual candy for full cross-browser compatibility, but, given that you're looking at iPhone/Android market I'd make a fool of myself and say "you'll be alright"

Have a look at [shapes of css](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) - possibly the only css-tricks article I'd find intriguing and useful - for creative inspiration of using css properties to accomplish what you're after. Be prepared that, with fancy gradients, you'd be having issues with matching the "stitch" between separate shapes.

Semantic markup is likely out of the question so go wild with all the elements you need (but do try and take advantage of :before and :after pseudoelements so as not to pollute the HTML completely). If it were up to me, I'd probably cheat a bit and make the thermometer tip fixed i.e. always either entirely filled or empty, and have the "progress" into a div with rounded TL and BL corners.

In retrospect, your example is already better, but here is the fiddle anyway :) http://jsfiddle.net/8dbjw/

Comment: Very nice. But this version has the progress going the wrong way.

Comment: @JohnFawcett: haha, I guess I was too focused on the "physical" thermometer that fills from the bottom. If you change float to "left" and only fill the bubble when it's at 100%, that would work. Good luck! :)